# What’s the exact sentiment in this sentence?

Tags: meaning-in-context

These two paragraphs are from the New Yorker magazine (March 06,2018)

> The pianist Maria Yudina (Olga Kurylenko), who has been engaged to play while Stalin lies in state, walks in, sees the body, and says, “Small. He looks so small.”
>
> This is the exact sentiment that the late oligarch Boris Berezovsky claimed Russian President Boris Yeltsin expressed upon being introduced to Vladimir Putin, in 1999.

My question is which part is the exact sentiment?

The sentiment that Boris Berezovsky claimed?

Or

The sentiment Boris Yeltsin expressed?

Or both

The whole sentence seems very smooth but I feel some preposition is missing.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer:

The late oligarch, Berezovsky, claimed that Yeltsin, upon being introduced to Putin in 1999, expressed the same sentiment the pianist, Yudina, had expressed upon seeing Stalin lying in state: "He looks so small". –

The "sentiment" is the the observation: "He looks so small".

> The pianist Maria Yudina (Olga Kurylenko), who has been engaged to
>   play while Stalin lies in state, walks in, sees the body, and says,
>   “Small. He looks so small.”

The present tense, "walks in", would suggest that these words are to be understood as being spoken contemporaneously with her walking in, or as if the speaker of those words had been present at that time, in which case they would be labeled "historical present".

> This is the exact sentiment that the late oligarch Boris Berezovsky
>   claimed Russian President Boris Yeltsin expressed upon being
>   introduced to Vladimir Putin, in 1999.'

If that sentence is referring to the first one, about the pianist Yudina, then "this" refers to the sentiment her words expressed.

Her words express the same idea that the oligarch, Berezovsky, claimed Yeltsin had expressed upon seeing Putin.

Comment: So if I change it to: What Russian President Boris Yeltsin expressed upon being introduced to Vladimir Putin in 1999 is the exact sentiment that the late oligarch Boris Berezovsky claimed.      The meaning will be same?

Comment: Wasn't Berezovsky reporting the sentiment expressed by Yeltsin? So Yudina expressed a sentiment that Yeltsin also expressed, if Berezovsky's claim can be believed.

Comment: @djna, yes my slip. I will correct.

Comment: The late oligarch, Berezovsky, claimed that Yeltsin, upon being introduced to Putin in 1999, expressed the same sentiment the pianist, Yudina, had expressed upon seeing Stalin lying in state: "He looks so small".

Comment: There is no indication that Berezovsky heard Yudina. The person reporting Yudina's speach (we do not know the identify of this person) is also aware of Berezovsky's report of Yeltsin's statement and is comparing the two.

Comment: @djna: I do not say anywhere that Berezovsky heard Yudina, What is the reason for this comment?

Comment: I'm trying to be helpful. I realise this was not your intention, but to my eyes there is an ambiguity in your sentence: "Berezovsky claimed that Yeltsin ... expressed the same sentiment the pianist Yudina had expressed". I am advising that a different phrasing would better indicate the boundaries of Berezovsky's claim.

Comment: Is there not the same ambiguity in the original?  I'm not introducing it.

Comment: Possibly in the first answer text, but in the quoted extracts (the one in yellow in the question) the separation ensures no ambiguity. My intention is to help folks for whom English is not a native language - they may well not be aware of the possibility of confusion, I should probably have attached my comment to the first answer too. Anyhow, if I've given offence I apologise.

Comment: No offence taken, merely confusion.